# Tuple<List<int>, List<int>> or a List<Tuple<int, int>>?

Tags: c#, tuples

Which is preferred and/or more efficient operation wise?

I ended up using a list of tuples, but am curious as to which one is preferred.

Opinions welcome but I would love a technical aspect I'm not finding via google.

Comment: The more relevant question is which is more appropriate for your particular need. A `Tuple<List<int>,List<int>>` does not imply a relationship between items at same indices within each list, it does not even imply the length of the lists will be the same. A `List<Tuple<int,int>>` clearly defines a relationship between the integer values. What is more appropriate for your program?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tuple of two Lists involves 2 reference types/pointers (1 for each List) per item, List of 2-Tuples involves only one (1 for each Tuple), so you save 8? Bytes for each item (forgot how big the pointer + .net metainfo is).

Does such a Micro-Optimization make sense? I doubt so. I'd rather advise to use whatever makes most sense from a business-logic perspective.

Answer (score 4):

It depends on what the data means.

If it's two lists of numbers, a tuple of lists would be correct. If it's a list of number pairs, the a list of tuples would be correct.

For whatever the integers mean, does it make sense that the lists would be of different lengths? If so, then you've probably got two independent lists, and a tuple of lists would be correct.

If the integers only make sense if the lists are of equal length, then you've probably got one list of number pairs, so a list of tuples would be correct.

Answer (score 4):

Those options have fairly different semantics.

One implies two lists that only have a tenuous connection to each other, and that an element in position `x` in List A doesn't correspond to the same location in List B. The following would be perfectly valid:

```
{ [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], [7] }
```

The other one is a list of paired elements. If you want to associate two numbers together, one from group A and one from group B, I'd suspect you want a `List<Tuple<int, int>>`. The above example would be invalid in this case, and you'll probably save yourself a lot of headaches double-checking things when you want to use the list.

As always, consider what you're trying to model and determine what data structure best maps to that. It's not worth sacrificing semantic integrity for a negligible performance improvement (at the very least, build it with the semantially correct version and hack it when a performance problem presents itself). I'm not sure if there even is a performance hissue here, but if anything, the second option should result in a lower memory footprint (since you have fewer lists allocated)

Answer (score 3):

They are for two different things.  The first is if you want a tuple which contains two lists of integers that aren't really associated, but the two lists are somehow related as a whole.  The second is a list of tuples with two integers, so integer A is somehow linked to integer B in the tuple.

Blindly guessing, you probably want option B.  This means that each tuple has two integers that are somehow linked.  I could be wrong, but of the two options, that is what most people want.  It's kind of like a Key Value Pair.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on what you want to achieve. I guess you want to have multiple pairs of `int`, then `List<Tuple<int, int>>` is the solution. There might be cases where the others are useful but I can't think of any from the top of my head.

Comment: Thanks for shedding some light, for some reason I was overlooking the aspect of relations in the data. I needed a one to one for a DateTime to a string and I suppose I subconsciously put it together to end up with an IEnumerable<DateTime, string>, now I can confidently close this class up!